# Why won't this event listener work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

```
    $('input[type=checkbox]').unbind().click(function(e){
        $(this).attr('checked', true)
        return false;
    });
```

I NEED to return false because I have an event on its parent and I don't want to trigger that.
It just WON'T check that checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').unbind().click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Edit: I'm not sure what you need `.unbind()` for, but you should beware that that is canceling any other events you've put on those checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a ] at the end of your jQuery selector

Comment: this should have been a comment, and now should be deleted